# Setting a new property to PFObject

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

I have a Parse.com cloud function that sends back a `PFObject`. In some cases I need to send back values for keys that don't exist in the `PFObject`. Is that possible?

This is what I tried:

```
var test = prodAndTitles["products"][0];
test["XOXO"] = "kisses";
prodAndTitles["products"][0] = test;
console.log("XOXO = " + prodAndTitles["products"][0]["XOXO"]);
```

This prints out `kisses` as expected.

But back in the app when I try to get the `XOXO` key it's not there:

```
NSLog(@"The product's XOXO %@", [self.product objectForKey:@"XOXO"]);
```

This prints out `null`.

I also tried changing the product type from `PFObject` to `id`, but it doesn't help.

Is there a solution, without going into the datastore class and creating dummy columns?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete answer to the problem I faced:

The issue is that none of the notations above works for the Parse.com backbone javascript objects that come from the datastore. This is the notation that does work:

```
testObject.set('TestProp', 'TestValue');
```

But this is still only part of the solution. When trying to send the `testObject` with the newly set property to the client ios app, it causes an error:

```
Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object.
```

The solution for this is to save the `testObject` after setting the property:

```
testObject.save();
```

This doesn't really make sense because I would have liked to add properties to the `testObject` and NOT save them to the datastore -- and it's a waste of a database call -- but it seems like Parse won't allow it. Weird.

Answer (score -1):

This is done with setting the correct ACL. The ACL has to be set for the user to be able to read and write. Then you can add new columns. In Cocoa it looks something like this:

```
PFACL *acl = [PFACL ACL];
[acl setReadAccess:YES forUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
[acl setWriteAccess:YES forUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
[test setACL:acl];
```

Comment: do you mean for the appropriate class? I don't want the user writing to it, and this is done on the server (the cloud) anyway. Do you mean I should use the master key to do this?

Comment: If you want to store a PFObject of a certain class which contains keys that are not yet available in that class, then you have to set the writeAccess to true for whatever instance you are sending it from. In my code example above it would be the current user. But I think you can also do this with the master key.